# Updating the store using redux actions

Tags: redux, reducers, dplyr

I need to update the store of my application using reducer. But I wanted to make it dynamic in a way that I need not to write different actions for updating the store at the same level.

Lets say below my store looks like this...

```
const store  = { nonPersistedState : {first :"", second : "", third : ""} }
```

all the first, second and third being on the same level of nonPersistedState.

Now for any of the above three if I want to update them, below is my action and reducer function

```
//action
dispatch({type: "UPDATE_MODEL", value : true, model : "first"}); /*model can be second or third as well*/


//store
    const initialState = {
        first :"", second : "", third : ""
    };

//reducer
    const nonPersistedState = (state = initialState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'UPDATE_MODEL':
                const localState = { ...state };
                localState[action.model] = action.value;
                return { ...localState };
            default:
                return state;
        }
    };

    export default nonPersistedState;
```

Now here I am creating a copy of the state first and then mutating it directly and then again returning the copy of the state.

So My question is, am I mutating the store or it is fine to do so? However I am not getting any warning or error message in the console and forms are getting re-rendered. Please provide inputs.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing it is correct. Using the spread operator to create the new state is even [referenced in the Redux doc](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usingobjectspreadoperator).

You could however slightly reduce the length of your code by assigning the new property directly at the same time you use the spread operator. It would look like this :

```
const nonPersistedState = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_MODEL':
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.model] : action.value
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```